# Simplest way to do a XMLHttpRequest in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping

I want to do a XMLHttpRequest POST in Ruby. I don't want to use a framework like Watir. Something like Mechanize or Scrubyt would be fine. How can I do this?

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest" is just an HTTP request. Use `Net::HTTP`.

Answer (score 2):

Mechanize:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.post 'http://www.example.com/', :foo => 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Example with 'net/http', (ruby 1.9.3):

You only have to put an additional header for the XMLHttpRequest to your POST-request (see below).

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'  # convenient for using parts of an URI

uri = URI.parse('http://server.com/path/to/resource')

# create a Net::HTTP object (the client with details of the server):
http_client = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

# create a POST-object for the request:
your_post = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

# the content (body) of your post-request:
your_post.body = 'your content'

# the headers for your post-request (you have to analyze before,
# which headers are mandatory for your request); for example:
your_post['Content-Type'] = 'put here the content-type'
your_post['Content-Length'] = your_post.body.size.to_s
# ...
# for an XMLHttpRequest you need (for example?) such header:
your_post['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

# send the request to the server:
response = http_client.request(your_post)

# the body of the response:
puts response.body
```

Answer (score 1):

XMLHTTPRequest is a browser concept, but since you're asking about Ruby, I assume all you want to do is simulate such a request from a ruby script? To that end, there's a gem called [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) which is very easy to use.

Here's a simple example (assuming you have the gem - install it with `gem install httparty`):

```
require 'httparty'
response = HTTParty.get('http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json')
puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

Comment: Hm, this is nice but I would need to login to the website I need to scrape beforehand, which HTTParty doesn't seem to do as easily as Mechanize for example.

Comment: @user1223734 ok, but if that's important, you should mention it in your question.